# Sample size calculation for study aiming to demonstrate non-inferiority of a drug

Tags: sample-size, epidemiology

I need to calculate the sample size required for an observational study in which incidence of disease is 19-29%. Population affected is 600,000 people.

The study has two samples similar on baseline characteristics treated 
 with two different drugs.

Statistical analysis will be chi-square and Fisher's test.
I have to demonstrate non-inferiority of one drugs with respect of the other one.
I don't have any other info.

Can anyone help me to calculate the sample sizes required in order to obtain power of 0.80
with an alpha 0.05?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Surely one of the applets at http://statpages.org/#Power will solve your problem.

Comment: @Roland How could you compute a sample size in a power study from a non-inferiority trial if you don't know the expected difference (or equivalently, the % of patients responding to the new treatment compared to the actual one)?

Answer (score 5):

[G*Power](http://www.psycho.uni-duesseldorf.de/aap/projects/gpower/) is a commonly-recommended program for sample size calculations.  I've only dabbled with it a couple of times in the past, but it's more than capable of handling the situation you describe.

Comment: (+1), excellent program. To spare the reader an extra click, you could link to the new version (G*Power3) which has a GUI for Windows and MacOS X: http://www.psycho.uni-duesseldorf.de/abteilungen/aap/gpower3/

Comment: Oops - thanks for that, caracal.  I just grabbed the link without noticing the content of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Are all your participants infected?
If you also have a placebo group and your df= 3 then according to Cohen (1992) at power = .8 and alpha = 0.5, for a chi square analysis will need 40 (39) participants if your effect is strong, 107 if it is a medium effect zise and 964 if its only a small effect. For only 2 groups the sizes are 26;87;725 for strong medium and small effect sizess respectively.
see: http://classes.deonandan.com/hss4303/2010/cohen%201992%20sample%20size.pdf
for the article